# Jira Insight automated attribute references when importing data from csv file

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to import objects from CSV file into Jira Insight, but I need to set references for some attributes from other object types. For example, in the attributes window of the object type, the Type should be Object and Type Value should be Team (referenced from another object type). I tried to write IQL in the "edit attributes mapping" section like Team=${Direction}, but it does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's very confusing....

Always use Label=${<name of the attribute in the destination object>}